# How can I change content page based on mat option -Angular-

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I'm working on an Angular 7 project and now I have to develop a page structured with an upper and static part where user can choose between different options, using mat-select material component.
Based on the option selected I want to show a different content in the page.

```
<div>
 <div>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>option1</mat-option>
    <mat-option>option2</mat-option>
    <mat-option>option3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </div>
...here I want to change dinamically between content1 || content2 || content3 based on the selection above...
</div>
```

How can I control the content dinamically, based on the selection?

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) to display different content depending on the select value:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select #select>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="select.value">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'option1'">The first option content</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'option2'">The second option content</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'option3'">The third option content</p>
</ng-container>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-985vaj?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.html)

---

In case you if you want to use templates as the content, you can use [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) directive to insert it.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select #select>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="select.value">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'option1'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="firstContent"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'option2'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="secondContent"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'option3'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="thirdContent"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #firstContent><p>The first option content</p></ng-template>
<ng-template #secondContent><p>The second option content</p></ng-template>
<ng-template #thirdContent><p>The third option content</p></ng-template>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-985vaj-migpri?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Valeriy!. My need is to switch between different content which I'd like to bring to me with an ng-container or ng-template. Think about them as form-group. How can I switch between them?

Comment: @R.Milos I added `<ng-template>` example too, hope it helps you.